# Why is my washing machine making this insanely loud noise during spin?

Tags: washing-machine, sounds

So the machine works fine and even spins fine too until the last bit of the spin cycle when it gets *crazy loud* (seriously - it's like a jackhammer)!

I uploaded a video - https://youtu.be/IsumwnjEqO8 (starts at second 25) - hoping someone can give me some ideas.

FWIW I did a little research and someone mentioned the counterweight - I don't see any damage to the counterweight and it seems to be attached quite tight too.

Comment: there could be a bearing issue, but its also possible something got between the drums. Great video. See if you can determine a soft spot turning the drum by hand and listening for an irregular scrape or change in resistance. Take the gasket out and inspect perhaps.

Comment: sounds like and looks like your load ( the clothes inside ) was out of balance and after vibrating for a while something gave way and broke.

Comment: @Alaskaman are you saying it seems like something broke _during_ this video? because this isn't a one-time issue this is what happens during every spin cycle - it's going, going, going, going, and then BAM for 10-20 seconds it's jackhammering!

Comment: @statichippo It was not clear to me that this was a recurring issue. Have you contacted the manufacturer?